# SQL CE how to prevent duplicate insert

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-ce

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO fpl_table 
                                                    (FLIGHT_ID, BPN_TIME, BPX_TIME, DAY_NB) 
                                                    VALUES (@FLIGHT_ID, @BPN_TIME, @BPX_TIME, @DAY_NB)
                                                    ON DUBLICATE UPDATE FLIGHT_ID = @FLIGHT_ID, BPN_TIME=@BPN_TIME,BPX_TIME=@BPX_TIME,DAY_NB=@DAY_NB"
                                                    ,connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FLIGHT_ID", format);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BPN_TIME", format1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BPX_TIME", format2);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DAY_NB", format3);
```

Hi everyone!

Ive got the problem with inserting 4 values into columns. I wanna prevent inserting 4 existing columns into database, i cant set them unique, cause the same column can be inserted with other 1,2 or 3 columns, i just wanna prevent only 4 existing columns insert.

Comment: You can add unique index on 4 columns at the same time

Comment: Use IF Exists to check if the 4 values exist in the specific columns, if not insert else update.

Comment: The data is viewed on datagridView, so i was trying to check if datagridView.rows[].cells[].value equals to data, do update, but, when it doesnt equal, the insert is being done many times

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER COMPACT 4.0 Database (.sdf)

Comment: @VTodorov As example, if insert 4 columns (data1,data2,data3,data4) in need to prevent the same columns inserting, so to be able to insert  (data1,data2,data5,data6). Unique index will work?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Place an unique constraint on all of the columns and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a unique constraint on 4 columns

```
CONSTRAINT UC_unique UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: As example, if insert 4 columns (data1,data2,data3,data4) in need to prevent the same columns inserting, so to be able to insert  (data1,data2,data5,data6)

Comment: you can user CONSTRAINT or unique index, both will work just fine

Comment: Okay, i will check that

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use a seperate function to find out duplicate records at first.

```
bool CheckDuplicateFlight(int FLIGHT_ID)
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"YOURCONNECTION STRING";
con.Open();
if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select count(*) from YOURTABLE where FLIGHT_ID= @FLIGHT_ID", con);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FLIGHT_ID",FLIGHT_ID);
int ExistingId= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
con.Close();
if(ExistingId> 0)
    return true;
return false;
}
if(CheckDuplicateFlight(FLIGHT_ID))
{
///// Your insertion/Update Code here
}
```

But Your Question is confusing a bit, Are you sure you want to insert record instead of update??? Insert query always inserts new record.

Comment: Yes, i am inserting new data every second, and wanna prevent all 4 duplicate columns inserting, but insert if for example only 3 columns in query are duplicate

Comment: You need to add Unique Constraints to 3 columns, and than using exception handling at your code, insert new record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Unique Constraints to 3 columns, and than using exception handling at your code, insert new record.